# Static linking of Libc

Tags: linux, gcc, static-linking, dynamic-linking, libc

I'd need to statically link all the dependencies of a binary in the binary itself (that is also the libc). I've tried the option -static-libgcc but it did not worked, the size of compiled binary is the same as the dynamic compiled one (that is without the static option).
Is it possible to do that? If so, how?

Comment: Just compile with `-static`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was pretty simple and has been given in a comment by the user Faust, merely just add -static as gcc option.